# Golf the Inverse of Exponential Generating Function

Tags: code-golf, math

Earlier, [we talked about exponential generating functions (e.g.f.)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83001/golf-the-exponential-generating-function-of-tangent).

## Task

You will take a few terms of a sequence.

Your task is to find another sequence with that many terms, whose e.g.f., when multiplied to the original e.g.f., would be exactly the constant function `1` accurate to that many terms.

That is, given `a0=1, a1, a2, ..., an`, find `b0=1, b1, b2, ..., bn` such that `a0 + a1x + a2x^2/2! + a3x^3/3! + ... + anx^n/n!` multiplied by `b0 + b1x + b2x^2/2! + b3x^3/3! + ... + bnx^n/n!` equals `1 + O(x^(n+1))`.

## Specs

- They will start at the zeroth power and will be consecutive.
- The first term is guaranteed to be `1`.
- All the terms are guaranteed to be integers.
- There will not be negative powers.

## Testcases

```
Input : 1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0 (this is actually cos x)
Output: 1,0, 1,0,5,0,61,0 (this is actually sec x)

Input : 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 (e^(2x))
Output: 1,-2, 4,-8, 16,-32 (e^(-2x))

Input : 1,-1,0,0, 0,  0,  0 (1-x)
Output: 1, 1,2,6,24,120,720 (1/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2+...)
```

Comment: When titling your next challenge, you may want to think about this http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8090/15599

Comment: Thank you! I have edited it away! I will bear that in mind next time!

Comment: Does the guarantee about integer coefficients apply only to the input, or to both input and output?

Comment: @feersum If the input has integer coefficients, then the output will also have integer coefficients.

Comment: [Example implementation given by Sp3000](https://ideone.com/145Oby).

Comment: [Borderline duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/842/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor How is that a duplicate at all?

Comment: Seriously? They're both polynomial division. To make it an exact duplicate you just have to add in the factorial weights and get the same endianness by transforming `p(x) = sum_i a_i x^i` to `p'(x) = x^n p(x^-1)` (i.e. reversing the input list of coefficients).

Comment: @PeterTaylor - it's not at all a duplicate. The processes are completely different, especially when you factor in that it's being done with exponential generating function format. It's not `p(x)=sum_i a_i x^i`, it's `p(x)=sum_i a_i x^i/i!`, and that changes the challenge quite significantly.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>91</s> <s>81</s> 77 bytes

```
!v=(b=[1;0v[r=2:end]];for i=r,j=0:i-2 b[i]-=binomial(i-1,j)v[i-j]b[j+1]end;b)
```

Usage: `![1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0]`

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Dennis!

This is a fairly straightforward implementation - it uses the fact that the "exponential" part causes a binomial to appear in the solution. Otherwise, it's just solving for the relevant coefficients.

Comment: `!v=(b=[1;0v[r=2:end]];for i=r,j=0:i-2 b[i]-=binomial(i-1,j)v[i-j]b[j+1]end;b)` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. I was using v[n=end] earlier to grab the length, but didn't think to use a full range like that.

Comment: I think that this answer contradicts your comment that "*the processes are completely different*".